# ¿Cómo puedo ingresar un Nodo en sql server desde TreeView? C# y Windows Form

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

Tengo un `TreeView` en 3 capas, ya me carga mi `TreeView` desde `sql` a visual studio mediante un funcion recursiva, pero no logro hacer que se me guarde en la base de datos, se me guarda en la vista porque logro ver el nodo con su nombre pero al cerrar la aplicación desaparece, y es porque no se está guardando en la base de datos, me pueden decir si es que tengo la función de `InsertarNodos` desde mi capa `Datos` mal?

Capa Datos:

```
        public void InsertarNodos(datostreeview parametros)
            {
            comandSql.Connection = con.AbrirConexion();
            comandSql.CommandText = "sp_InsertarNodos";
            comandSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", parametros.Codigo);
            comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", parametros.Nombre);
            comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoRapido", parametros.Codigorapido);
            comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idpadre", parametros.Idpadre);

            comandSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comandSql.Parameters.Clear();
            con.CCerraConexion();
            }
```

Capa Negocio:

```
         public void InsertarAttr(string codigo, string nombre, string codigorapido, int idpadre)
            {
            obje_cdtreeview.Codigo = codigo;
            obje_cdtreeview.Nombre = nombre;
            obje_cdtreeview.Codigorapido = Convert.ToInt32(codigorapido);
            obje_cdtreeview.Idpadre = idpadre;
            }
```

capa presentación:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (editar == false)
        {
            try
            {

                if (textBox1.Text != "" || textBox2.Text != "")
                {
                    nodoSeleccionado = treeView1.SelectedNode;
                    padre = int.Parse(dataTableNodos.Rows[int.Parse(nodoSeleccionado.Tag.ToString())]["IdPCuentas"].ToString());

                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ".";
                    string Codigo = textBox1.Text;
                    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.ToUpper();
                    string Nombre = textBox2.Text;
                    textBox3.Text = Codigo.Replace(".", "");
                    string Codigorapido = textBox3.Text;

                    objc_treeview.InsertarAttr(Codigo, Nombre, Codigorapido, padre);

                    MessageBox.Show("Se guardo el Registro");

                    textBox1.Enabled = false;
                    textBox2.Enabled = false;


                    TreeNode nodoInsertado = new TreeNode();
                    nodoInsertado.Text = Codigo + "  " + Nombre;
                    nodoSeleccionado.Nodes.Add(nodoInsertado);
                }
```

Corregido el error pero sigue sin guardarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITO**, tras la rectificación del error anterior

El método `InsertarNodos` insertar nodos parece correcto, sin conocer el contenido del procedimiento almacenado `sp_InsertarNodos`.

El problema es que este método no lo llamas en ninguna parte, jamás va a entrar en la inserción de la base de datos.

** FIN DE LA EDICIÓN **

Parece un error muy simple:

Agregas el parámetro

```
comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("Idpadre", parametros.Idpadre);
```

Cuando debería ser

```
comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idpadre", parametros.Idpadre);
```

Por otro lado asegúrate que los parámetros `@Codigo`, `@Nombre`, `@CodigoRapido` y `@Idpadre` están exactamente escritos en tu procedimiento almacenado-

Comment: No había visto ese error, lo corregí y sigue sin guardarme, estoy trabajando con un ´TreeView´ no se si el método de guardado en la capa datos sea diferente,o el guardado en la capa presentación sea correcto

Comment: He editado la respuesta, a ver si encuentras la forma de llamar al método `InsertarNodos`

Comment: Muchas ya me ingresa, si era así, no había visto que no estaba llamando ni pasando los parámetros a mi función. ahora tengo otro problema, mi carga de `TreeView` es con una `funcion recursiva`, y cuando señalo el nodo que acabo de ingresar me aparece este error, y no se como solucionarlo:

`excepcion no controlada

system.nullreferencexception: "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"
system.windows.form.treenode.tag.get devolvio null`

Comment: `public void MostrarNodosText(TreeNode nodeData)
        {
            DataTable dataTableNodos = new DataTable();
            dataTableNodos = objc_treeview.RecogerDatos();
        
                filasDatos = dataTableNodos.Rows[int.Parse(nodeData.Tag.ToString())]; // aqui
            textBox1.Text = filasDatos["Codigo"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = filasDatos["Nombre"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = filasDatos["Cod_rapido"].ToString();
          
        }`

Comment: Ummmh, dificil de ver. Yo de ti abriría una nueva pregunta describiendo este nuevo problema y con el código relevante e indicando dónde se produce el error

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias eso haré, gracias por la ayuda